# Text artefact in Facebook dialog with Unity ios app

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have one problem with Unity3D ios app.
I'm using Prime31 plugin (SocialNetworking) to send messages to FB.
Sometimes when i trying to post the app to the stream I can see following problem (html tags like   etc in the dialog form within the app. But in facebook stream everything looks ok.
All texts are in XML file (UTF-16).
Please let me know if you have any idea how to remove tags from message in dialog form.
Thank you.